# How do I upload JSP file content to textarea

Tags: java, jsp

I want to edit an jsp file from textarea in browser. So i need to upload jsp content to textarea.
For example i have a readMe.jsp file like that:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<h1>Read Me</h1>
<p> This is read me content</p>
```

I want this edit like that:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<h1>Read Me</h1>
<p> This is read me content</p>
<hr>
<h2>Read Me Second Head</h2>
<p>This is read me content 2</p>
```

The way I think to be able to do this in the browser is to upload the jsp content to textarea and edit it from there. Does anyone know how I can do this?
If I have a way to edit a jsp file differently from the browser, it can also be.
Thanks.

Comment: Please be also aware that this requires a bit of security processing. So a standard component would be best.

Comment: @JoopEggen Sorry i can't understand. what do you mean by a standard component?

Comment: JSP pages are compiled into servlets when the WAR is loaded by the servlet container. They cannot be updated at run time

Comment: There are some frameworks. Try to search for an example of JSP with editable content. It is something like one page with a form and text-area for input, and then (the same?) page with read-only HTML as you showed, maybe with edit links/buttons. Of course you do not want a user to embed malicious javascript/links or even just textual grafitti. If you store the text in a database, prevent SQL injection by using a PreparedStatement. _(A bit too much for a start.)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example how a JSP page can be edited from a browser.

`webapp/readme.jsp` is a page to edit.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read Me</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Read Me</h1>
<p> This is read me content</p>
<p><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit/readme">Edit this page</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`webapp/edit/readme.jsp` contains a form within that a content of a `readme.jsp` page can be edit.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit | Read Me</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>'Read Me' edit page</h1>
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit/readme">
    <label>
        <textarea name="newContent" cols="96" rows="16">${content}</textarea>
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`EditReadMe.java` is a servlet.

The method `doGet` is triggered by the *Edit this page* link from the `webapp/readme.jsp`. It read content from the  `webapp/readme.jsp` file and passes it to the  `webapp/edit/readme.jsp`.

The method `doPost` is responsible for working with the form from the `webapp/edit/readme.jsp` and updating content for the `webapp/readme.jsp` file.

```
package com.example.editjsp;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

@WebServlet(name = "readMeEditor", value = "/edit/readme")
public class EditReadMe extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "/readme.jsp";
    private Path pathToFile;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        pathToFile = Path.of(getServletContext().getRealPath(RESOURCE_PATH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String contentToEdit = Files.readString(pathToFile);
        req.setAttribute("content", contentToEdit);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/edit/readme.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        Files.writeString(pathToFile, req.getParameter("newContent"));
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + RESOURCE_PATH);

    }

}
```